# Pandas read CSV and Seaborn - ValueError: Could not interpret input

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, seaborn

## The data

I load a dataframe from a CSV that looks like this :

```
$> cat data/min_max.out 
inc nb_core matrix_name min_ratio   max_ratio   size
1   [4] blur    -0.04448199907127215    0.013399553205103443    0.37
2   [4, 4]  blur    -0.04453722751332001    0.013489091403327214    0.68
3   [16]    blur    -0.00284065321351612    0.0010090201007384447   0.39
```

## The code

When loading it into Pandas and trying to plot it with Seaborn I get the error `ValueError: Could not interpret input 'matrix_name'`

---

```
data = pd.read_csv("data/min_max.out", sep="\t")
print(data["matrix_name"])
```

Output

> ```
> 0    blur
> 1    blur
> 2    blur
> Name: matrix_name, dtype: object
> ```

---

```
sns.countplot(x="matrix_name", df=data)
```

Output

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-32-ed2cdb4855ad> in <module>
>       1 print(data["matrix_name"])
> ----> 2 sns.countplot(x="matrix_name", df=data)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in countplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, dodge, ax, **kwargs)
>    3551                           estimator, ci, n_boot, units,
>    3552                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
> -> 3553                           errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
>    3554 
>    3555     plotter.value_label = "count"
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, orient, color, palette, saturation, errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
>    1605         """Initialize the plotter."""
>    1606         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient,
> -> 1607                                  order, hue_order, units)
>    1608         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
>    1609         self.estimate_statistic(estimator, ci, n_boot)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
>     153                 if isinstance(input, string_types):
>     154                     err = "Could not interpret input '{}'".format(input)
> --> 155                     raise ValueError(err)
>     156 
>     157             # Figure out the plotting orientation
>
> ValueError: Could not interpret input 'matrix_name'
> ```

This is a silly plot for testing. You wouldn't find anything interesting in it and this is normal.

This is run in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: `sns.countplot(x="matrix_name", df=data)` should be `sns.countplot(x="matrix_name", data=data)`. You are just passing in an arbitrary keyword called `df`.

Comment: So it can't interpret the column name because you never gave it the dataframe to look in.

Comment: It's kind of surprising that it doesn't check that you provided a valid `data` argument and complain about that first.

Comment: @Barmar Surprising indeed